# Use of change filament tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I have just written a usage guidance for [change-filament](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/change-filament).

I assume that the tag is for, and only for, methods to change filament *during* a print. ***Not*** for questions which ask whether someone should change from using one type of filament to another type, *between completed prints*..?

If that assumption is correct, then there are two questions that are incorrectly tagged:

- [Why won't my filament feed through the extruder anymore?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/7982/why-wont-my-filament-feed-through-the-extruder-anymore)
- [Strange problem with quality, what might be the reason for these bubbles?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/8690/strange-problem-with-quality-what-might-be-the-reason-for-these-bubbles)